# When using awk to parse a CSV file, why does it ignore empty cells?

Tags: bash, csv, awk

I have some scripts which use `awk` to parse a CSV file. I have noticed that, if a cell is empty, `awk` simply moves to the next cell. This means, if I ask it to read column 4, but that cell is empty, it prints the data from column 5, e.g.:

```
echo "1@2@3@@5" | awk -F "@*" '{print $4}'
```

My expected result is that it will print nothing, because column 4 is empty.

- Why is `awk` skipping column 4?
- How can I get `awk` to not ignore empty columns?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is not what you think. awk is not ignoring empty cells; it is parsing that line as 4 fields instead of 5.

```
[me@home]$ echo "1@2@3@@5" | awk -F "@*" '{print NF}'
4
```

That's becuase you're using `@*` as your field separator which allows one or more consecutive `@` as your field separator (`@`, `@@`, `@@@`, ... are all valid field separators).

Try using `-F "@"` instead.

```
[me@home]$ echo "1@2@3@@5" | awk -F "@" '{print NF}'
5
[me@home]$ echo "1@2@3@@5" | awk -F "@" '{print $4}'

[me@home]$ echo "1@2@3@@5" | awk -F "@" '{print $5}'
5
```

Comment: `awk` is actually being kind here and ignoring empty matches for the regex. Because the regex is nullable (matches empty strings), the input line "1234@@5" should, strictly speaking, actually split into fields 1, 2, 3, 4, 5. Or perhaps even with an extra empty field at the beginning and end. The regex matches at every position in the string, after all.